# Отправка на почту данных. Android

Tags: java, android, json, email

Необходимо реализовать следующую процедуру:
Клиент заходит в приложения, выбирает "Заказать ...", ему выходит форма " ФИО, город, номер телефона".
После нажатия кнопки "Заказать", эта форма, скорее всего в формате json, должна передаваться на почту поставщику. Какими инструментами это можно реализовать? Благодарю за ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Добрый день для работы с таким API обычно используют библиотеку [Retrofit](https://habr.com/ru/post/314028/) и [OkHttpClient](https://habr.com/ru/post/281965/).